# General information about ide's, libraries and include?

Tags: c++, ide

When you install and IDE such as DEV C++, I am able to create programs and compile my main function by including files as cmath, iostream, string and such. My question is the class implementations of stream and string etc... does the IDE install them in a special directory and this is why I am able to include them or are they available on my system already (preinstalled with windows) and the IDE looks for these.

Also are their definitions stored in .cpp and .h files as well?

Comment: Include files come in two broad categories -- standard language support files (in your case, the C and C++ Standard Libraries), and OS-specific headers.  One comes from the compiler vendor, one from the OS vendor.  But usually neither group will be present until you install developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files would be included with the IDE, as they're required for basic programming. If you open the files, you can see that the copyright is the people who made the IDE (in most cases, probably), and that the files won't be the same between different IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the IDE has installed them. Ususally IDEs have settings that say what directories to search for include files.